# Snapin not appearing in the 'Add or Remove Snap-ins' dialog?

Tags: mmc, snap-in

Im having issues trying to get a custom snapin to display in the Add/Remove Snap-ins dialog (MMC). Is this done though a registry key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use installutil to register the snap-in.  That will get it showing up in the Add/Remove Snap-ins dialog.